# Get executable name during runtime

Tags: fortran

Using the pgf90 compiler, is it possible to get name of the executable during runtime? It would be nice to save this information in the output, together with the svn revision number (this is already implemented and done during the preprocessing).

thanks

Comment: Can I ask how you store the svn revision number?

Comment: the svn version number-story is quite complicated. We get the version number during compilation (svn info) and then use it as a preprocessor option to get it into the actual fortran code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortran 2003 introduced GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT. Besides getting the command argument, it allows to retrieve the command name by which the program was invoked. This is passed in argument number 0. Perhaps your compiler is recent enough to support it. The exact text of what is passed in the argument depends on the compiler.

```
program cmd_name
     character :: cmd*100
     call get_command_argument(0, cmd)
     print *, "command name : " // cmd(1:len_trim(cmd))
end program
```

with Ifort 13.1 on Windows, this prints:

```
 command name : cmd_name
```